# build_runner não executa o comando flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs --verbose

Tags: mobile, flutter, dart

Olá,
criei um projeto com o comando flutter create.
como vou usar modular a ativei o slidy no projeto com o comando slidy start
até ai tudo bem, mas quando tento rodar o comando para gerar os .g.dart, ele não executa.
na verdade executa, mais fica rodando em um loop infinito.
já tentei fazer clean, get packages, e até mudei o environment para outra versão
até agora nada
segue minha pilha:

```
PS C:\Users\MARCOS\Documents\mobile\github_search\github_search> flutter pub get                                                           
Running "flutter pub get" in github_search...                       0,6s
PS C:\Users\MARCOS\Documents\mobile\github_search\github_search> flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs --verbose 
[ +105 ms] executing: [C:\src\flutter/] git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[  +58 ms] Exit code 0 from: git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[        ] 2ae34518b87dd891355ed6c6ea8cb68c4d52bb9d
[        ] executing: [C:\src\flutter/] git tag --contains HEAD
[ +185 ms] Exit code 0 from: git tag --contains HEAD
[        ] 1.20.1
[  +12 ms] executing: [C:\src\flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[  +35 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[        ] origin/stable
[        ] executing: [C:\src\flutter/] git ls-remote --get-url origin
[  +27 ms] Exit code 0 from: git ls-remote --get-url origin
[        ] https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
[  +61 ms] executing: [C:\src\flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[  +30 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[        ] stable
[  +45 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidMavenArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[   +3 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[  +19 ms] Artifact Instance of 'MaterialFonts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'GradleWrapper' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidMavenArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +5 ms] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FontSubsetArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[  +24 ms] Using C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache for the pub cache.
[  +10 ms] executing: C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\pub.bat run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs --verbose
Precompiling executable...
Precompiled build_runner:build_runner.
[INFO] Generating build script...
[INFO] Generating build script completed, took 347ms

[INFO] Creating build script snapshot......
[INFO] Creating build script snapshot... completed, took 13.4s

[INFO] BuildDefinition:Initializing inputs
[INFO] BuildDefinition:Building new asset graph...
[INFO] BuildDefinition:Building new asset graph completed, took 714ms  

[INFO] BuildDefinition:Checking for unexpected pre-existing outputs....
[INFO] BuildDefinition:Checking for unexpected pre-existing outputs. completed, took 1ms

[INFO] Build:Running build...
[INFO] build_resolvers:Generating SDK summary...
[SEVERE] mobx_codegen:mobx_generator on test/app/app_controller_test.dart:

Bad state: Unexpected diagnostics:
C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\pkg\sky_engine\lib\ui\channel_buffers.dart:119:41 - This requires the 'non-nullable' language feature to be enabled.
C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\pkg\sky_engine\lib\ui\channel_buffers.dart:152:17 - This requires the 'non-nullable' language feature to be enabled.
C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\pkg\sky_engine\lib\ui\channel_buffers.dart:88:62 - This requires the 'non-nullable' language feature to be enabled.
C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\pkg\sky_engine\lib\ui\channel_buffers.dart:153:38 - This requires the 'non-nullable' language feature to be enabled.
C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\pkg\sky_engine\lib\ui\channel_buffers.dart:186:51 - This requires the 'non-nullable' language feature to be enabled.
C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\pkg\sky_engine\lib\ui\channel_buffers.dart:133:32 - This requires the 'non-nullable' language feature to be enabled.
C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\pkg\sky_engine\lib\ui\channel_buffers.dart:154:25 - This requires the 'non-nullable' language feature to be enabled.
C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\pkg\sky_engine\lib\ui\channel_buffers.dart:18:17 - This requires the 'non-nullable' language feature to be enabled.
C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\pkg\sky_engine\lib\ui\channel_buffers.dart:64:4 - This requires the 'non-nullable' language feature to be enabled.C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\pkg\sky_engine\lib\ui\channel_buffers.dart:168:32 - This requires the 'non-nullable' language feature to be enabled.
C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\pkg\sky_engine\lib\ui\channel_buffers.dart:47:14 - This requires the 'non-nullable' language feature to be enabled.
C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\pkg\sky_engine\lib\ui\channel_buffers.dart:159:38 - This requires the 'non-nullable' language feature to be enabled.
C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\pkg\sky_engine\lib\ui\channel_buffers.dart:132:37 - This requires the 'non-nullable' language feature to be enabled.
C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\pkg\sky_engine\lib\ui\channel_buffers.dart:118:48 - This requires the 'non-nullable' language feature to be enabled.
C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\pkg\sky_engine\lib\ui\channel_buffers.dart:19:11 - This requires the 'non-nullable' language feature to be enabled.
```

Answer (score 1):

Esse é um problema do build_runner, faça um downgrade para o 1.10.1.
Pelo que entendi o build_runner depende do dart 2.10 que esta em prerelease, no canal dev.

Comment: Me salvou man, valeu!

Answer (score 0):

Usando o canal stable você pode fazer um override na dependencia analyzer.

```
dependency_overrides:
    analyzer: '0.39.14'
```